# Angular2 unescaped curly braces limitations

Tags: angular

I'm wondering why angular2 disapproves of unescaped/unclosed curly braces only in certain situations.

```
<div>{something{{some.value}}}</div> //doesn't work

<div directiveAttr="{something{{some.value}}}"></div> //no problem
```

Angular 1.x didn't have a problem with mixed braces, angular2 also seems to not mind them in certain places. But when it is in the template, I get this error:

```
Template parse errors:
Unexpected character "EOF" (Do you have an unescaped "{" in your template? Use "{{ '{' }}") to escape it.)
```

Why would it work in attributes, but not in the inner text part?

Comment: Most likely related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9571 Any way, opening an issue makes more sense than asking why it's not working on SO when it's not working indeed.

Comment: I saw a [test for it](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/74b57dfa7d1aafd79ee385b8274537b1aa83a5c2/modules/%40angular/compiler/test/ml_parser/lexer_spec.ts#L731) so I assumed it's a feature, it's just weird to me that it is allowed in some places and not others. I'm scared it will stop working where it does work for me currently, I thought I'd ask about the possible reasons.